# Rspec and FactoryGirl.attributes_for params refactor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, factory-bot

I am current getting my tests to pass, but I wanted to see if I could refactor the tests with a `let(:message)` or some kind of variable

Mailer tests

```
 describe "Contact Form" do                                                                                                                         

    context "when a valid message" do                                                                                                                

      it "sends an email" do                                                                                                                         
        post contact_create_path, message: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:message)                                                                      
        expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.to).to eq(["#{ENV["MVP_USERNAME"]}"])                                                              
      end                                                                                                                                            
    end
```

The part I want to refactor is `message: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:message)`. 
I tried to doing something like

```
context "when a valid message" do
    let(:message) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:message) }        
    it "sends an email" do                                                                                                                         
      post contact_create_path, message                                                                      
      expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.to).to eq(["#{ENV["MVP_USERNAME"]}"])                                                              
    end
```

but that outputs 
`ActionController::ParameterMissing:
       param not found: message`

other attempts

`@message = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:message)`

`message = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:message)`

I could leave it like this, but I feel that I it should be changed for some reason. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look to be in need of refactoring to me, but the trouble is the version you have in your `let` statement is simply a hash of attributes. It's missing the `:message` key.

```
let(:message) { message: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:message) }
```

That should work, but as I said I don't think you need to refactor it. I'd actually just make sure you're mixing in the FactoryGirl syntax methods into your specs so you can drop the `FactoryGirl` and just use `attributes_for` directly.

In your spec helper:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```